# Adding colors for an particular event day in jquery full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, jquery, background-color

I'm using a jQuery full calendar to show leaves taken by people which are coming from one of my database tables.
There are different types of leaves. I need to show each leave type in different colors in the particular day.
Suppose I took an Annual leave on 1st of November and a Casual leave on 3rd of November.
So I need to show these two different leave types in two different colors in the same calendar.

Could you please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `className` parameter in the events. That should help.

Example json

```
{
    title     : 'Some title',
    start     : '2012-11-05',
    className : 'casual_leave',
}
```

Example css

```
.casual_leave{
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Similarly, you can have many different classes and assign `background-color`, `color` and (if I am not mistaken) `border` details in css